# javascript assign function from class name

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to assign function from another class name in javascript. Here is what i mean in script:

```
classA = function() {

     this.direction = 1;
     this.someFunction = function() {
          this.direction = 0;
     }   

}

classB = function() {

    this.direction = 2;
    this.anotherFunction = classA.function

}

objA = new classA;
objB = new classB;
objB.anotherFunction();
console.log(objB.direction); // 0
console.log(objA.direction); // 1
```

How can I achieve that? I can't find much information about the prototype variable of javascript but i feel like this is possible with that.

EDIT: Fixed a typo

Comment: What is this? `objB = new objB;`?

Comment: oops. it was a typo. fixed now

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do want to "borrow" a function from classA to be used in classB?

Comment: thats exactly what I want to do but inside the class definition. not like `objB.anotherFunction = objA.someFunction`

Comment: I could answer you ,the problem is down the road ,all solutions have side effects ,if you dont understand "this" in javascript you should learn about "this" is javascript first. and prototypal inheritance.A quick fix would be a disservice to you.

Comment: i do understand this in javascript but i don't understand the prototype in javascript and the relationship between `this` and `prototype`. If someone can provide me with an article that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in the following way:

```
var classA = function() {
     this.direction = 1;
     this.someFunction = function() {
         this.direction = 0;
     };
};

var classB = function() {
    this.direction = 2;
    this.anotherFunction = new classA().someFunction;
};

var objA = new classA;
var objB = new classB;
objB.anotherFunction();
console.log(objB.direction); // 0
console.log(objA.direction); // 1
```

Comment: this one fits my situation better as I should have used prototypes but  have already written 700 lines of code using the other way...

Comment: FYI this way uses more memory and is slower. Hopefully not a problem for your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I consider the right way to do this...

```
var classA = function() {
     this.direction = 1;
}

classA.prototype.someFunction = function() {
     this.direction = 0;
}   

var classB = function() {
    this.direction = 2;
}

classB.prototype.anotherFunction = classA.prototype.someFunction;

objA = new classA();
objB = new classB();
objB.anotherFunction();
console.log(objB.direction);
console.log(objA.direction);
```

Comment: As mpm said, if you want to write your own classes, read up online about Javascript classes specifically, and about Javascript's prototypal inheritance. It would also help you to look at some open-source JS projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `prototype` to define the functions:

```
var classA = function () {
    this.direction = 1;
}
classA.prototype.someFunction = function () {
    this.direction = 0;
}


var classB = function () {
    this.direction = 2;
}
classB.prototype.anotherFunction = classA.prototype.someFunction;

objA = new classA();
objB = new classB();
objB.anotherFunction();
console.log(objB.direction); // 0
console.log(objA.direction); // 1
```

Comment: Yup, don't worry, not accusing you of anything! :)

Comment: I would have but I have already defined all my functions using `this.func = function() {}`

Comment: Are there so many of them that refactoring is out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Looks like all the answers are similar.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates using the `prototype` object: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ757/

```
function ClassA(){
    this.direction = 1;
}

// Expose method
ClassA.prototype.someFunction = function(){
    this.direction = 0;   
}

function ClassB(){
    this.direction = 2;

    // Instance property
    this.anotherFunction = ClassA.prototype.someFunction;
}

// Instances
objA = new ClassA();
objB = new ClassB();

console.log(objB.direction); // Outputs 2
console.log(objA.direction); // Outputs 1

objB.anotherFunction(); // Sets to 0

console.log(objB.direction); // Outputs 0

objA.someFunction(); // Set to 0

console.log(objA.direction); // Outputs 0
```

As pointed out by Hamza in the comments, I've made the mistake of assigning `ClassA.prototype.someFunction` to `this.anotherFunction` (copy/paste laziness).

Ideally, we want to go with the approach others have suggested (assigning `someFunction` to ClassB's `prototype` object), since this avoids creating those unique instances every time we call `new`. However, I'd like to leave it here since it does illustrate a slight difference between how others have suggested and this answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be setting `ClassB.prototype.anotherFunction`.

Comment: Hah, I probably should. Just to mix things up, I'll keep it as an instance property (and make a note of how not to do this...)